# Searching for specific text in SmarTerm via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to search for a specific line of text in a SmarTerm application window opened via VBA and then copy the rest of the row of data into a cell in a worksheet.  Previously this was accomplished using a reflection session but I now have no option other than to use SmarTerm.

The code that worked with reflection is:

```
Found = Session.FindText("SEARCH TEXT", 0, 0)
If Found Then
str_get_string_from_reflection = .GetText(Session.FoundTextRow, 19, Session.FoundTextRow, 60)
Trim (str_get_string_from_reflection)
rng_range_constants_col_A.Offset(0,3).Value = "Search Text: " & str_get_string_from_reflection
End If
```

Sadly this doesn't work with the SmarTerm solution, I've tried using the `Session.StringWait.MatchString` command but this doesn't seem to search in the entire visible screen.

Any help that can be offered here will be very much appreciated

I've tried using the SmarTerm Macro Guide (http://www.esker.com/fm/others/eval-smarterm/bin1211/macro.pdf) but can't locate anything other than `StringWait.MatchString` or `StringWait.MatchStringExact` that supports searching in the available text.  Sadly this only seems to search on the last line of the text, rather than on the whole visible screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Session.ScreenText(row, col, page, chars)`